I am not able to Add update or fetch a Phone Number for persons in Affinity API
I'm working with the Affinity API to create new persons in my database. The API allows me to add basic information like name and email, but I’m struggling to include a phone number in the request.
Here’s a simplified version of the cURL request I'm currently using to create a person
curl -X POST "https://api.affinity.co/persons" \
-H "Authorization: Basic <your_api_key>" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "emails": ["john.doe@example.com"]
}'

I’d like to include a phone number in this request. The documentation doesn’t seem to have clear instructions on how to add phone numbers when creating a person.
Questions:

Is there a specific field or format required to include a phone number in the POST /persons request?
If phone numbers can't be added directly when creating a person, what is the recommended way to associate a phone number with a person after they have been created?

Any help or example of a request that successfully includes a phone number would be greatly appreciated!

Please read the instructions for using the tag [tag:api] which says "DO NOT USE". You should follow the site guidelines to get answers.
